# Creating a list of sums of lists in a list (Scheme)?

Tags: list, sum, scheme, racket

I'm not very familiar with Scheme, so I am having trouble with the problem.

Write a scheme procedure which takes a list of list of numbers each containing at least 1 number. Your procedure should return a list containing the individual sums of each of those lists of numbers. For example: ((1 2 3) (4 5) (6) (7 8 9 10)) -> (6 9 6 34)

So far I am trying to create a listCreator function and a sumHelper function. I'm still doing testing, but I'm getting stuck with an error.

```
    (define lst '((1 2 3) (4 5) (6) (7 8 9 10)))

    lst

    (define sumHelper
      (lambda (lst)
        (if (null? lst)
             0
             (+ (car lst) (sumHelper (cdr lst))))))

    (define listCreator
      (lambda (lst)
        (if (null? lst)
             0
             (sumHelper (car lst)))))
```

My error is: car: expects a pair, given 2

Any help or direction for solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: Opps, that is incorrect. It should be `(map (lambda (v) (apply + v)) lst)`. But  I have an answer that explains what was wrong with your listCreator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `listCreator` didn't build nor apply itself to the rest of the list:

```
(define listCreator
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst)
         '()
         (cons (sumHelper (car lst)) (listCreator (cdr lst))))))
```

Also the value if the list is null should be the empty list: `'()` and not `0`

Once these changes are made your code works as written.